# Entity Framework - Disctinct by property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have this code:

```
var models = await _assignment
                .Include(a => a.Rule)
                .Include(a => a.User)
                .Select(x => new AssignmentResponse
                {
                    Id = x.User.Id,
                    RuleId = x.RuleId ?? -1
                })
                .ApplyFilterAndPaginationAsync(_webQueryProcessor, request.Options, cancellationToken);
```

I am trying to get the first assignment for each user (there can be many ruleIds for one userId, but I only want the first).

My attempt (not working):

```
var models = await _assignment
                .Include(a => a.Rule)
                .Include(a => a.User)
                .Distinct(a => a.User.Id)
                .Select(x => new AssignmentResponse
                {
                    Id = x.User.Id,
                    RuleId = x.RuleId ?? -1
                })
                .ApplyFilterAndPaginationAsync(_webQueryProcessor, request.Options, cancellationToken);
```

How can I achieve that without loading them all into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a table of `Users` and a table of `Assignments`, and there is a one-to-many relation between Users and Assignments: every User has zero or more Assignments, every Assignment belongs to exactly one User, namely the User that the foreign key refers to.

You also have a table of `Rules`. There is a relation between `Assignments` and `Rules`. I'm not sure about the kind of relation : does every Assignment have exactly one Rule? (one-to-many: Rules have zero or more Assignments, Assignment has foreign key to rule).
Or is there a many-to-many relation: every Assignment has zero or more Rules, and every Rule is a Rule in zero or more Assignments.

Because this is not part of your question, I won't go deep into this.

If you have followed the [entity framework conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), you will have classes like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every User has zero or more Assignments (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Assignment> Assignments {get; set;}
}

public class Assignment
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every Assignment is the assignment of exactly one user, using foreign key:
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}

    // One-To-Many: Every assignment has one Rule using foreign key
    public int RuleId {get; set;}
    public virtual Rule Rule {get; set;}

    // alternative: many-to-many: every assignment has zero or more Rules
    public virtual ICollection<Rule> Rules {get; set;}
}
```

> In Entity Framework, the non-virtual properties represent the columns of the tables; the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many).

The foreign key `UserId` is a real column in table Assignments, hence it is non-virtual. `User` is not a column in Assignment, but a relation with Assignment, hence it is declared virtual.

For completeness the DbContext:

```
public class WorkDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
    public DbSet<AssignMent> Assignments {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Rule> Rules {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Because I followed the entity framework conventions, this is all that entity framework needs to detect the tables, the columns of the tables and the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many), including the foreign keys. Only if you want to deviate from the conventions, especially different identifiers, you need to use Attributes or fluent API.

> I am trying to get the **first** assignment for each user

Problem: what is the *first* assignment?

- Is that the assignment with the oldest Date?
- is that the assignment with the lowest Id?
- is that the assignment that comes first in the database? (fairly unpredictable)

### Use virtual ICollections

When using entity framework to fetch data in a one-to-many relation, it is usually easier to use the virtual properties. Entity framework knows your relations, and creates the proper (Group-)Join for you.

```
using (var dbContext = new WorkDbContext())
{
    var usersWithTheirFirstAssignment = dbContext.Users.Select(user => new
    {
        // Select only the User properties that you plan to use
        Id = user.Id,
        Name = user.Name,
        ...

        // Get the "first" Assignment
        FirstAssignment = ... // TODO: implement
    })
    .ToList();
}
```

To get the FirstAssignment, if that is the one with the oldest Date, OrderBy Date, before selecting the properties:

```
FirstAssignment = user.Assignments.OrderBy(assignment => assignment.Date)
    .Select(assignment => new {...})
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or if the first assignment is the one with the lowest Id:

```
FirstAssignment = user.Assignments.OrderBy(assignment => assignment.Id)
    .Select(assignment => new {...})
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or if the first assignment is just the one that is first in the database:

```
FirstAssignment = user.Assignments.Select(assignment => new {...})
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

> if you have a one-to-many relation, and you want for every "one" item its "many" subItem, start at the "one" in a Select and use the `virtual ICollection` to fetch the "many" subItems.
> If, on the other hand, you want items, each item with its one and only parent that the foreign key refers to, start at the "many" side, and use the virtual property to select the "one" side properties.

### Intermezzo: Why select only the properties that you plan to use?

Database management systems are extremely optimized in selecting data. One of the slower parts of the query is the transfer of the selected data from the DBMS to your local process. Hence it is wise to limit the amount of selected data as much as possible.

If you use `Include` to select related classes, the complete related subclass is selected, inclusive the foreign keys.

So if User [10] has 1000 Assignments, every Assignment will have a foreign key `UserId` with value 10. You will be transferring this same number 10 more than 1000 times. What a waste of processing power.

Another reason to use Select if you don't plan to change the fetched data, is that every DbContext has a ChangeTracker. If you fetch an table row without Select, the fetched object is stored in the ChangeTracker, together with a copy. You get a reference to the original. If you change values, the values of the original in the ChangeTracker are changed. When you use `SaveChanges`, all Originals in the ChangeTracker are compared by value with the copy, to see which items need to be updated.

So if you fetch 1000 users, your ChangeTracker will contain 1000 originals and 1000 copies. If you only change one before calling SaveChanges, the code must check every non-virtual property of each of these 1000 Users, while only one user will be changed. What a waste of processing power!

> When querying data, always use Select and select only the properties that you actually plan to use. Only fetch complete classes or use Include if you plan to change the fetched data.

So in the Select above:

```
FirstAssignment = user.Assignments.OrderBy(...)
    .Select(assignment => new
    {
        // Select only the Assignment properties that you plan to use
        Id = assignment.Id,
        Date = assignment.Date,

        // don't Select the foreign key, you already know the value:
        // UserId = assignment.UserId

        Rule = new
        {
            // you know the drill by now: only the rule properties that you plan to use!
            Id = assignment.Rule.Id,
            Name = assignment.Rule.Name,
            ...
        },
    })
    .FirstOrDefault(),
```

### Alternative: use the foreign key in the Select

Although using the virtual ICollection seems to me the most intuitive solution, you could also use the foreign key to select the FirstAssignment:

```
var usersWithTheirFirstAssignment = dbContext.Users.Select(user => new
{
    Id = user.Id,
    Name = user.Name,
    ...

    FirstAssignment = dbContext.Assignments
        .Where(assignment => assignment.UserId == user.Id)
        .Orderby(...)
        .Select(...)
        .FirstOrDefault(),
}
```

OrderBy and Select are the same as above. Entity Framework will create a GroupJoin similar to the one when using the virtual ICollection.

### But I want to do the (Group-)Join myself!

Some people don't trust entity framework. They don't use the virtual ICollection, but prefer do the GroupJoin themselves. If you want to do that, you need to do something like:

```
// GroupJoin Users and Assignments:
var usersWithTheirFirstAssignment = dbContext.Users.GroupJoin(dbContext.Assignments,

user => user.Id,                    // from every user take the primary key
assignment => assignment.UserId,    // from every assignment take the foreign key to the user

// parameter resultSelector: from every User and its zero or more assignments, make one new
(user, assignmentsOfThisUser) => new
{
    Id = user.Id,
    Name = user.Name,
    ...

    // the first assignment: order and select like described above
    FirstAssignment = assignmentsOfThisUser.OrderBy(...)
        .Select(...)
        .FirstOrDefault(),
}
```

Comment: Jesus Harald, that's a whole blog post I got here! Not only did it work, but actually taught me a lot. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `group by`

```
var models = await _assignment
                .Include(a => a.Rule)
                .Include(a => a.User)
                .GroupBy(a => a.User.Id)
                .Select(x => new AssignmentResponse
                {
                    Id = x.Key,
                    RuleId = x.FirstOrDefault().RuleId ?? -1
                })
                .ApplyFilterAndPaginationAsync(_webQueryProcessor, request.Options, cancellationToken);
```

Moreover, I think that you don't need to include Rule? If you do not reference any field of it.